# Getting attribute from overridden property via a linq Expression

Tags: .net, linq-expressions, getcustomattributes

I'm trying to use `GetCustomAttributes()` to get an attribute defined on a property. The issue is that the property is an overridden one and I can't work out how to extract the overridden one from the expression. I can only work out how to get the base class's one.

Here's some code

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute 
{
  //... 
}

public abstract class Text
{
  public abstract string Content {get; set;}
}

public class Abstract : Text
{
  [MyAttribute("Some Info")]
  public override string Content {get; set;}
}
```

Now I am trying to get the `MyAttribute` out of the abstract class. But I need to get it via an `Expression`. This is what I have been using:

```
Expression<Func<Abstract, string>> expression =  c => c.Content;
Expression exp = expression.Body;
MemberInfo memberType = (exp as MemberExpression).Member;

var attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(memberType, true);
```

Unfortunately `atts` ends up as empty. The problem is that `menberType` ends up being for `Text.Content` instead of the `Abstract.Content` class. So when I get the attributes, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not working because the `MemberExpression` ignores the overrides and returns the property form the base type `Text` that's why you don't find your attribute.

You can read about this problem here: [How to get the child declaring type from an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466582/how-to-get-the-child-declaring-type-from-an-expression)

However you have all the information in the expression and you can get your attribute with a little more reflection (quick and dirty sample):

```
Expression<Func<Abstract, string>> expression = (Abstract c) => c.Content;
Expression exp = expression.Body;
MemberInfo memberType = (exp as MemberExpression).Member;

var attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(
expression.Parameters[0].Type.GetProperty(memberType.Name));
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. I searched for something similar but didn't find that one.

Comment: That solution you gave is the work around I have been using up till now so nice to get some independent support for that one :-) Thanks