# How to tell if MemberInfo represents an override

Tags: c#, reflection, polymorphism

Given the following code:

```
public class Base {
    public virtual void Method() { }
}

public class Derived : Base {
    public override void Method() { }
}

...

var baseMethodInfo = typeof(Base).GetMember("Method")[0];
var derivedMethodInfo = typeof(Derived).GetMember("Method")[0];
```

Is it possible to determine if the derivedMethodInfo represents a method declaration which overrides another in a base class?

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466582/how-to-get-the-child-declaring-type-from-an-expression?rq=1) it was observed that had `Method` been declared abstract (and not implemented) in the base class, derivedMethodInfo.DeclaringType would have turned up as Base, which makes sense after reading @EricLippert's comments.  I noticed that in the present example, since the derived class re-declares the method, that `derivedMethodInfo.DeclaringType == derivedMethodInfo.ReflectedType`, viz. Derived.

There doesn't seem to be any connection between baseMethodInfo and derivedMethodInfo, other than their names are the same and their respective declaring types appear in the same inheritance chain.  Is there any better way to make the connection?

The reason I ask is that there appears to be no way to distinguish, through reflection, between the earlier example and the following one:

```
public class Base {
    public virtual void Method() { }
}

public class Derived : Base {
    public new void Method() { }
}
```

In this case as well, the Derived class both declares and reflects a member called Method.

Comment: [`GetBaseDefinition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.getbasedefinition.aspx) should distinguish the two situations, I guess.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes; that's a much better answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: You're absolutely right.  I missed it because I was working with MemberInfo instead of MethodInfo.  I'll accept this if you make it into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a more specific class `MethodInfo` which derives from `MemberInfo`. Note that not all kinds of members can be virtual (fields cannot, for example).

If you say

```
var derivedMethodInfo = typeof(Derived).GetMethod("Method");
```

then you can check if

```
derivedMethodInfo.GetBaseDefinition() == derivedMethodInfo
```

or not. See [documentation for `GetBaseDefinition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.getbasedefinition.aspx) where they also have a code example.

Answer (score 4):

A method shadowing a `virtual` method will have the `VtableLayoutMask` flag set in `Attributes`.

Note that an ordinary `virtual` method (with no similar name from a base type) will also have this flag set.

This flag appears to indicate that the method introduces a new entry in the VTable.

Comment: Was just playing around in LINQPad, and that's indeed the case. +1 well worth it!

Comment: If I understand your answer, it sounds as though the `VtableLayoutMask` attribute indicates if the method can be overridden, not if it is overriding.  In particular, if the new method was declared as `public new virtual void Method()`, then again there would be no way to tell if it shadows the base method or not (here it doesn't).

Comment: @CSJ: No.  `new virtual` has `VtableLayoutMask` (since it introduces a new Vtable entry); `override` does not.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.  I thought that shadowing meant overriding; in fact it means using the `new` keyword.  In conclusion I should look for no `VtableLayoutMask` attribute.

Comment: @CSJ: And check that it is virtual.

Comment: VtableLayoutMask is not actually a name of an attribute, it is a bit-mask.  The debugger isn't smart enough about enums to display good info.  The bitmask tests only one bit in the attribute, you really want to look for MethodAttributes.NewSlot.  If it is not set then you can assume the default, MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot