# Is it possible to tell apart overridden and hidden method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Consider these variants:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Doit()
    {
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public new virtual void Doit()
    {
    }
}
```

or

```
class B : A
{
    public override virtual void Doit()
    {
    }
}
```

I cannot find the difference in the returned results of the call `typeof(B).GetMethod("Doit");`

In both cases `MethodInfo.DecalringType` is class B and other properties seem the same.
Do I miss something or there is no way to distinguish them?

**Update:**

When I ran the sample in LINQPAd I noticed slight difference in `Attributes` property:

for `new virtual` value was - *PrivateScope, Public, Virtual, HideBySig, **VtableLayoutMask***
for `override` - *PrivateScope, Public, Virtual, HideBySig*

**Update 2:**

I googled about `VtableLayoutMask` and came back to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623188/how-to-tell-if-memberinfo-represents-an-override)

**Udate 3:**

resulting code:

```
public static class MethodInfoExtensions
{
    public static bool IsOverriden(this MethodInfo method)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(method != null, "method");

        return method.IsVirtual
               && !method.IsStatic
               // overriden exactly in this class
               && method.ReflectedType == method.DeclaringType
               // not new and not declared for the first time in the class 
               && method.GetBaseDefinition() != method;
    }
}
```

Comment: "VtableLayoutMask" is misleading info from the debugger, it is not actually a name of an attribute bit.  It is a bit-mask, used to test for other bits.  Of which there are actually only 1, bit #16 is 0 to indicate ReuseSlot, it is 1 to indicate NewSlot.  Which is what you are really looking for, test for MethodAttributes.NewSlot to keep your code readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DeclaringType` will be different if it was hidden with `new`. For example, run:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void WillBeInheritted()
    {

    }
    public virtual void WillBeOverridden()
    {

    }
    public virtual void WillBeHidden()
    {

    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override void WillBeOverridden()
    {

    }
    public virtual new void WillBeHidden()
    {

    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(var meth in typeof(B).GetMethods())
        {
            Console.Write(meth.Name);
            Console.Write(": ");
            Console.Write(meth.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType.Name);
            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(meth.DeclaringType.Name);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
WillBeOverridden: A B
WillBeHidden: B B
WillBeInheritted: A A
WillBeHidden: A A
ToString: Object Object
Equals: Object Object
GetHashCode: Object Object
GetType: Object Object
```

`WillBeInheritted` has `A` as the declaring type for both the method and the base definition's declaring type.

`WillBeOverridden` has `A` for the base definition's declaring type, `B` for the declaring type.

`WillBeHidden` has two versions, the hidden one in `A` and the hiding one in `B`. This makes sense when we consider:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;
b.WillBeHidden(); // calls hiding method.
a.WillBeHidden(); // calls hidden method on same object.
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** The documentation seems to imply that `IsHideBySig` is the answer, but it does not appear to be the case in practice.

Another strategy is to rely on the presence of the [NewSlot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodattributes.aspx) attribute:

```
public static bool HasNewModifier(this MethodInfo method)
{
     return (method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.VtableLayoutMask)
         == MethodAttributes.NewSlot;
}
```

---

> *Original, incorrect answer follows.*

You can rely on the [IsHideBySig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.ishidebysig.aspx) property. It will be `true` if the method has the `new` modifier.

Note the above only applies to *C# methods*. The documentation elaborates with:

> When a member in a derived class is declared with the C# `new` modifier
>   or the Visual Basic `Shadows` modifier, it can hide a member of the same
>   name in the base class. C# hides base class members by signature. That
>   is, if the base class member has multiple overloads, the only one that
>   is hidden is the one that has the identical signature. By contrast,
>   Visual Basic hides all the base class overloads. Thus, `IsHideBySig`
>   returns `false` on a member declared with the Visual Basic `Shadows`
>   modifier, and `true` on a member declared with the C# `new` modifier.

Comment: It is true in both cases as I can see

Comment: @voroninp, do you mean it is `true` even if the method is `override` and not `new`?

Comment: yes, exacly. See my question, I added an update. It's the only difference I've noticed so far.

Comment: @voroninp, the documentation also mentions the `NewSlot` attribute, I updated my answer with this strategy.

Comment: Interesting enough but decompiled source shows that NewSlot equals to VtableLayoutMask

Comment: @JonHanna Yes, sure, I check for virtual. You answer is also very good. At least there is less magic with strange attributes =)

Comment: Also, `VtableLayoutMask` exists so that if other vtable-layout related flags where added, you could get all of them by masking. As such its possible a future framework would have more than one flag seen with that mask and `(method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.VtableLayoutMask) == MethodAttributes.NewSlot` would return false for a method with `NewSlot` set. If you are going to take this approach you want either `(method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.MethodAttributes.NewSlot) == MethodAttributes.NewSlot` or `(method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.MethodAttributes.NewSlot) != 0`

Comment: @JonHanna wrote: _if the question had `public override void Doit()` instead of `public override virtual void Doit()` ..._ Combining `override` and `virtual` keywords is never allowed in C#, so the question does not provide legal C# code. An `override` may or may not be combined with the `sealed` keyword, however. The best way to find out if a method is an override is to compare its `.DeclaringType` to its `.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType` because `GetBaseDefinition()` gives the top-most (non-override) method of the "slot". That is the `virtual` or `abstract` method declaration.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen sorry, that was a hasty copy-paste, and it's now too late to edit. Correction: `NewSlot` on its own isn't fully informative: It'll be false for an overridden method, or a non-virtual method, including a non-virtual hiding method (if the question had `public new void Doit()` instead of `public new virtual void Doit()`), so if you take this approach you'd also have to check whether `Virtual` was set or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`GetBaseDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.getbasedefinition.aspx)** to find out where this method was first declared.

For example if you let `var mi = typeof(B).GetMethod("Doit");` you can check if `mi.GetBaseDefinition() == mi` or if `mi.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType == typeof(B)` etc.

---

Here is an example:

```
class Animal : object
{
  public virtual void M()
  {
  }
}
class Mammal : Animal
{
  public override void M()
  {
  }
}
class Giraffe : Mammal
{
}
static class Test
{
  internal static void Run()
  {
    var mi = typeof(Giraffe).GetMethod("M");

    Console.WriteLine(mi.ReflectedType);                     // Giraffe
    Console.WriteLine(mi.DeclaringType);                     // Mammal
    Console.WriteLine(mi.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType); // Animal
  }
}
```

The `MethodInfo` instance `mi` represents the `override` as inherited (unchanged) to `Giraffe`. And `mi.GetBaseDefinition()` fetches another `MethodInfo` which represents instead the method `Animal.M` which does not carry the `override` keyword in the C# source.